# SQLite code optimization

Tags: c#, excel, sqlite

I am a hobbyist programmer and writing a reporting tool to export values from an SQLite database to Excel.

The Excel part is written and working, the data I am retrieving from SQLite is creating a block in the program and taking several minutes to process.

I have rewritten the code out using generic values to help illustrate the processes. The initial `populateList` module is taking a negligible amount of time, but I have included it below as that is the providing the data for the `doStuff` module. The `populateList` currently retrieves approximately 500 distinct records.

I need the program to iterate through all the values retrieved by the `populateList` and do several counts. It is then populating another list `valuesCount` with the counted values.

I tried to improve the speed by looping through the list without closing the SQLite connection, but the improvement wasn't enough. Is there a more efficient way to retrieve this information from the databse?

```
public list<string>populateList()
{
List<string>values = new list<string>();
using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(Passer.connstr))
{
    con.Open();
    string distinctValues = "SELECT DISTINCT \"value list\" FROM valueTable order by \"value list\" ";
    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(distinctValues, con))
    {
        SQLiteDataReader sqReader;
        sqReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (sqReader.Read())
        {
            values.Add(sqReader["value list"].ToString());
        }
    }
}
return values;
}

public void doStuff()
{
bool blanks = false;
string singleValue = string.Empty
string query = string.Empty;

List<string> getInitialValues = populateList();
list<string> valuesCount = new list<string>();
    using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(Passer.connstr))
    {
        con.Open();
        for(int i = 0; i < getInitialValues.Count; i++)
        {
            blanks = false;
            singleValue = getInitialValues[i];
            if(singlevalue == "")
            {
                singleValue = \"\";
                blanks = true;
            }
            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
            {
                string statement = string.Empty;
                switch(x)
                {
                    case 0:
                        statement = "SELECT COUNT(*) from valueTable where \"column1\" = ";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        statement = "SELECT COUNT(*) from valueTable where \"column2\" = \"condition 1\" and \"column1\" = ";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        statement = "SELECT COUNT(*) from valueTable where \"column3\" = \"condition 3\" and \"column1\" = ";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        statement = "SELECT COUNT(*) from valueTable where \"column4\" = \"condition 4\" and \"column1\" = ";
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        statement = "SELECT COUNT(*) from valueTable where \"column5\" = \"condition 5\" and \"column1\" = ";
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        statement = "SELECT COUNT(*) from valueTable where \"column6\" = \"condition 6\" and \"column1\" = ";
                        break;                      
                }
                if (blanks == true)
                {
                    query = System.String.Format("{0}{1}", statement, singleValue);
                }
                else 
                {
                    query = System.string.format("{0}\"{1}\"", statement, singleValue);
                }
                using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, con))
                {
                    string countValues = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                    valuesCount.Add(countValues);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are querying the database multiple times to get the same information.
I would suggest not to do any db calls on dostuff method, rather use a single query for fetch the records form valuetable.

then you can do the count operations on the list itself.

For example get

```
"SELECT 'valueCol' , 'col1', 'col2' from valueTable"
```

would be your only query and you would store it in a list(say valueList).

Then on C# side you can use

```
 //not actual code just a sample idea
    var distinctValues = valueList.select(v => w.valueCol).Distinct()
    var count = 0;
    switch(case): 
        case 0:
            count += valueList.where(v => v.col1 == condition).Count();
                break; //and so on...
```

Comment: Thank you SadiRubaiyet, i have changed the code around as you suggested and there is a significant performance boost.

Answer (score 1):

Consider writing it as a single SQL query.

You are performing many queries when it very much looks like you simply need to perform a 'conditional count' on the columns. The SQL would be along the lines of

```
select 
  val,
  col1 = sum(case when col1 = 'cond1' then 1 end)
from valtbl
group by val
```

you wouldn't even need the first method to get the list of distinct values.

Alternatively as the table seems reasonably small select what you need into a list of 'rows' and use Linq to Objects to do the counts.